# Entity Framework JOINs when datatype does not match

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

While migrating an old SQL query I found that column used in join condition have different data types int & bigint. I am not sure how that was supported in SQL server!

However while using Model-First flavor of EF, these columns map to int & long respectively.
In LINQ I can no longer write join condtion also I can't use `Convert.ToInt32` as EF does not recognize these methods at run-time.

So I am dead-locked. How do I handle this?

Comment: Well its a legacy query so probably no harm using a stored procedure in this case so long as you control it with EF migrations

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Are you suggesting that rather than migrating using LINQ I should put old SQL into `SP` and invoke that?

Comment: Sure, this is a rare case, right? We all so some unusual things to get legacy code working.

Answer (score 2):

**int to long**

You do not need to use `Convert.ToInt32`. You can just join on the columns, there shouldn't be any issue between int and bigint.

---

**long to string**

You can use [SqlFunctions.ConvertString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466276(v=vs.110).aspx) in your join like this:

```
var query = from x in context.Table1
            join y in context.Table2
            on x.StringColumn equals SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal)y.LongColumn).Trim()
            select ...
```

Comment: Its not only int & long. But I see certain join condition on long & string.

Comment: @Abhijeet - I updated the answer with an example of long & string